# The number of items printed from my vector is inconsistent with the supposed number of items IN the vector

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

I'm making a word search game and I've been trying to get a random set of numbers from a preexisting `vector` that's been shuffled. I can do so, but when I iterate through the `vector` and print the strings, the number of strings is inconsistent with the value returned by numWords, which supposedly returns the number of items in a `vector`.

I've been looking at it over and over, but I cannot figure out why it's inconsistent most of the time. Also, I was trying to get a fixed set of 8 words in `THE_SET`, but the inconsistency pushed me to try a random number of words, but it's still inconsistent. If there's a way I could make `THE_SET` consistently 8 random words, I'd like to know.

**EDIT: I've got the problem solved, THANKS. [: And I also understand now. I just don't know whether I was confusing debugging with anything or not...since I click "Debug" to check for errors and run my file. Huh. I'm still a beginner and practicing, so I forget some things I've read... And sorry if I misinterpreted anyone.

Everything else seems to be working fine.

```
// word search.cpp : main project file.

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <ctime>
#include <vector>
#include <cctype>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

void dispBoard(const vector<string>& wordSet);
void checkGuess(string entry, const vector<string>& wordSet);
int numWords(const vector<string>& wordSet);

string alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
int numLeft = 0;

int main()
{
    srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(time(0)));


    random_shuffle(alphabet.begin(), alphabet.end());

    vector<string> wordSets;
    wordSets.push_back("CHICKEN");
    wordSets.push_back("BEEF");
    wordSets.push_back("DISHONOR");
    wordSets.push_back("LAWNMOWER");
    wordSets.push_back("LEGEND");
    wordSets.push_back("PROGRAMMING");
    wordSets.push_back("DEVELOPER");
    wordSets.push_back("HOMEWORK");
    wordSets.push_back("TERRIBLE");
    wordSets.push_back("VACATION");
    wordSets.push_back("PYTHON");
    wordSets.push_back("RUBY");
    wordSets.push_back("POKEMON");
    wordSets.push_back("BORDERLANDS");
    wordSets.push_back("INFINITE");
    wordSets.push_back("SMASH");
    wordSets.push_back("BROTHERS");
    wordSets.push_back("SNAKES");
    wordSets.push_back("HAMSTER");
    wordSets.push_back("ELEPHANT");
    wordSets.push_back("BUFFALO");
    wordSets.push_back("PILLOW");
    wordSets.push_back("PASTA");
    wordSets.push_back("RAMEN");

    random_shuffle(wordSets.begin(), wordSets.end());
    vector<string> THE_SET(wordSets.begin(), wordSets.begin() + (rand() % 15 + 1)); //vector of current word set, formed from wordSets
    //I'd like this to be fixed at 8 words
    int MAX_WORDS = numWords(THE_SET);  //reinitialization to number of words in THE_SET--why is it inconsistent with printed words???
    numLeft = numWords(THE_SET);

    cout << "number of words left: " << numLeft << " and MAX WORDS: " << MAX_WORDS << "\n\n";   //checks num of words

    vector<string>::iterator iter;

    for(iter = THE_SET.begin(); iter != THE_SET.end(); iter++)      //prints words in THE_SET--but number of words counted by hand are usually 
    {                                                               //inconsistent
        cout << *iter << " ";
    }

    cout << "\n\n";
    string entry; 


    do {            //main loop of game
        dispBoard(THE_SET);
        cout << "You have " << numLeft << " words left to find. \n\n";
        cout << "(Enter 'EXIT' if you wish to quit the game.)\n";
        cout << "Enter your find in UPPERCASE: ";
        cin >> entry;
        cout << "\n\n";
        if(entry == "EXIT") {
            return 0;
        }
        else {
            checkGuess(entry, THE_SET);
        }

    } while(numLeft != 0);

    cout << "Congrats! You found all " << MAX_WORDS << " words!!\n\n";

    system("PAUSE");
}

void dispBoard(const vector<string>& wordSet) { //this displays a bunch of random letters around the words in THE_SET
    vector<string>::const_iterator iter;
    for(iter = wordSet.begin(); iter != wordSet.end(); iter++) 
    {
        cout << alphabet.substr(rand() % 8, (rand() % 32 + 1)) << *iter << alphabet.substr(rand() % 8, (rand() % 32 + 1)) << endl;
    }
}

void checkGuess(string entry, const vector<string>& wordSet) {
    if(entry == "EXIT")
    {
        cout << "Quitting game.\n\n";
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        vector<string>::const_iterator iter;
        for(iter = wordSet.begin(); iter != wordSet.end(); iter++) {
            if(entry == *iter)
            {
                cout << "That's right! " << entry << " is in the search!\n\n";
                numLeft--;
            }

        }
    }
}

int numWords(const vector<string>& wordSet)     //supposed to count number of strings in a given vector, but it's inconsistent. Why??
{
    unsigned int i = 0;
    vector<string>::const_iterator iter;
    for(iter = wordSet.begin(); iter != wordSet.end(); iter++)
    {
        i++;
    }
    return i;
}
```

Comment: A debugger an going through your program step by step might be a better method than just _'looking over and over at it'_!

Comment: Of course I used a debugger :/ I'm not that stupid, but this is a problem the debugger cannot catch since the code was doing something I didn't know it would do. And thanks for mistyping what I wrote.

Comment: "*this is a problem the debugger cannot catch*" - doubt it - "*the code was doing something I didn't know it would do*" - that seems like the use case for a debugger.

Comment: @izaheichou - The debugger didn't show you that you had 25, 26, 27, 28, ... items in the vector on each `push_back`? That debugger stinks if it didn't clearly show you this.

Comment: Please, if the debugger caught it, I WOULD HAVE KNOWN. Please stop giving me useless help when I already have received good help below! I debug regularly, but this error wasn't caught by it. I'm not 12, please save me these useless comments.

Comment: @izaheichou - There is no "error" for the debugger to catch. It is perfectly legal to start with 24 items and add items by calling `push_back`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie No, it didn't--is it supposed to? I'm using Visual Studio 2010 express and it said nothing of the sort. I even put back the (24) and tried it again. Thanks for not being snide like the others....

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie -- Exactly! So I don't know why these people kept telling me to debug as if I didn't do that already. If it had been an error, I would have put an error message.

Comment: @izaheichou _'but this error wasn't caught by it'_ I have the feeling you're confusing debugging with exceptions thrown (and automated debugger startup due to this)

Comment: @izaheichou - The VS debugger should show the number of items in the vector, and each entry is blank. Just for learning purposes, put the 24 back in the code, but this time, inspect the vector with the debugger just before you start calling `push_back`. You should see that it started out with 24 items.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you execute these lines:

```
vector<string> wordSets(24);
wordSets.push_back("CHICKEN");
```

`wordSets` has `24` empty items an the item `"CHICKEN"`. I suspect, you didn't mean that. Changing the first line to:

```
vector<string> wordSets;
```

should fix the wrong number of items problem.

If you want to reduce the number of times memory is allocated by calls to `push_back`, you can use:

```
vector<string> wordSets;
wordSets.reserve(24);
```

This will make sure that `wordSets` has sufficient memory to hold upto `24` objects.

Answer (score 2):

To elaborate on *R Sahu*'s answer: Writing

```
vector<string> wordSets(24);
```

is equivalent to

```
vector<string> wordSets;
wordSets.resize(24);
```

I.e. *wordSets* is initialized to be a vector with 24 elements that you can access using the `operator[]`. Adding an element to the vector through `push_back` increases the size of the vector to 25.

What **you probably meant to do** was to reserve enough room for 24 strings such that the vector need not resize and reallocate memory for the first 24 additions. You can achieve this as follows:

```
vector<string> wordSets;
wordSets.reserve(24);
```

Also take a look at [reserve()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/reserve/) and [resize()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/resize/) on [cplusplus.com's reference of std::vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/).